# Eureka registration based on host

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I'm working with a simple example of a Spring Boot Eureka service registration.  I am using  spring-boot-starter 1.5.4.RELEASE, spring-cloud-starter-eureka 1.3.1.RELEASE. The eureka server should register the client instance only if the registration request are coming from white-listed servers.

Is there any out of box feature available in Spring Boot Eureka to achieve this requirement.

Comment: You can use basic security. Without username and password eureka service does not accept a client.

Answer (score 1):

The username and password for login is more preferred.

1. Add maven dependency:

   `<dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
         </dependency>
     </dependencies>`
2. Add username and password and other configurations to your configuration file `application.yaml`, note that the `client.service-url.defaultZone` should contain username and password:

`security:
  basic:
    enabled: true
  user:
    name: user
    password: 123456
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    service-url:
     defaultZone: http://user:123456@${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/`